# Prove that sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1+\sin(n\pi/2) }{n^2}$ converges using comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So i got this geometric series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty  } \frac{1+\sin(n\pi/2) }{n^2}$$

and im supposed to prove it converges using the comparison test.

The thing i dont get is why
$\sin(n\pi/2)$ alternating between $-1$ and $+1$ does not cause any problems.

Comment: It is not a geometric series!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use that $$\frac{|1+\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})|}{n^2}\le \frac{2}{n^2}$$
and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{3}$$

Comment: Do we really need the absolute value?

Comment: We want to use that the partial series is $\nearrow$ and bounded thus convergent. The increasing part is obtained because the series has positive terms, which is indeed the case here without absolute value, but we generally prefer proving absolute convergence since it is a stronger claim than just convergence.

Comment: Nice answer, but there's a small typo: The denominator of the summand should be $n^2$, not $n^3$.

Comment: Only a small typo! Rainy day feeling!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

As a minor issue, we should start from $n=1$.

Then observe that

$$0\le \frac{1+\sin(n\pi/2) }{n^2} \le  \frac{2 }{n^2}$$

Comment: Nice to see you're back

Comment: @GabrielRomon Thanks! Bye